# I am confuse which one is correct between these two , for me both seems correct?

Tags: grammar

He is at the library studying for his German test on Wednesday
He is studying in the library for his German test on Wednesday

Comment: Why do you believe they are not both correct?

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically speaking, the sentences are both correct. As a stylistic matter, though, there is room for improvement.

Answer (score -3):

He is studying in the library for his German test on Wednesday......is more correct.The 'at' makes the first answer wrong.

Comment: "At" would be correct if the library were a separate building (and therefore a separate location).

Comment: Using "at" is perfectly fine. It's a preposition denoting where "he" is. "In" is also a preposition, but its meaning is different from "at." "In" connotes being inside of something whereas "at" doesn't necessarily mean that one is inside something.

Comment: @Nathan M. is correct: [at is a preposition](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/at) denoting the location - there's no "right or wrong" answer but if you want to be really precise, [Google n-gram](https://i.imgur.com/VzpEKbK.png) shows a preference for *in the library*, rather than *at the library*; probably because *at the library* is more idiomatic.